# How to listen for messages on a single channel in Twilio Programmable Chat

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-conversations

Using [twilio-chat.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio-chat) how can I listen for messages on a single channel? I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54687896/how-to-listen-for-new-message-from-multiple-channels-in-twilio-programmable-chat) which asks how to listen on multiple channels, but I can't find anything describing how to do this on a single channel.

(Where `token` is an [Access Token](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/create-tokens)).
Currently I have:

```
let client = await Twilio.Chat.Client.create(token);
client.on('messageAdded', function(message){...})
```

Comment: future visitors also [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54687896/how-to-listen-for-new-message-from-multiple-channels-in-twilio-programmable-chat) if you want to listen for messages coming to multiple channels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `messageAdded` event is fired when messages are added to the *channel*. The client picks up on all of these events on all subscribed channels.

You need to handle the `messageAdded` event on the channel itself, rather than the client. To do this, you first need to *get* the channel - in this case by [SID](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/3.3.4/docs/Client.html#getChannelBySid__anchor), then handle the event:

```
let client = await Twilio.Chat.Client.create(token);
let channel = await client.getChannelBySid(sid);
channel.on('messageAdded', function(message){...})
```

Comment: That1Guy is a hero!